# Connecting Android Game to iOS Game Center

Tags: android, ios, game-center

I've implemented a game for iPhone that takes advantage of  the Game Centers multiplayer & achievements API, and I'm now in the making of an Android port.
Is it possibl to connect my android port to Apple's Game Center to allow cross-platform multiplayer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use GameCenter API on Android. There are other gaming platforms you can use, like `OpenFeint`

Comment: I know it isn't natively supported, the question is if there's an open-source implementation of the Game Center protocol

Comment: If you want cross platform multiplayer, you'll have to write your own implementation. As far as I know, there aren't any open source alternatives right now. There are open source libraries for Bonjour for Java (Cocoa Touch also supports Bonjour) if you want local cross platform multiplayer.

Comment: SwarmConnect.com provides an Android SDK as well (similar to openfeint/scoreloop)

Answer (score 0):

For the multiplayer functionality you can use the [Skiler SDK](http://www.skiller-games.com), which also provide a good Achievements system..